# How to set dynamically content size of a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scrollview

I'm working on an app that uses a `UIScrollView` to display an image and some text. I have the whole thing to work properly when i set a fixed size for the `UIscrollView` ex:

```
[scrollview setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, 480))];
```

My problem is that the text is fed via some web services an the size varies so i guess i will have to set the content size dynamically, can somebody please tell me how to do that. For info the size of the image is fixed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ContentSize can be set whenever you want. So, you can calculate the size required dynamically and use the setContentSize command

Comment: or your problem is finding the size dynamically???

Comment: Yes actually that is the problem, finding the size dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You need scrollview to set content size, so first of all set deragand drop uiscrollview in view and set IBOutlat and deleget and than after viewdidload in set content size. like that..

```
if (PhotoPathArray.count > 0)
{
    int y=5,x=-87;

    for(int i=0;i<[PhotoPathArray count];i++)
    {

        if(i%3==0 && i!=0)
        {
            y=y+100;
            x=13;
            scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, y+130);
        }
        else
        {
            x=x+100;
        }


        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn.tag=i;
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(imegbtnclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(x,y, 95,95);
        [scroll addSubview:btn];
    }
}
```

;

Answer (score 0):

```
// Calculate scroll view size
float sizeOfContent = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < [myScrollView.subviews count]; i++) {
    UIView *view =[myScrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    sizeOfContent += view.frame.size.height;
}

// Set content size for scroll view
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myScrollView.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent);
```